# Loading PDF file from Firebase Storage in Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, firebase-storage

i'm working on app and i want to loading pdf from firebase storage to an flutter app i search a lot about this and i don't find anything can help me
for example like in the image i want when i click to cour or TD.. the pdf show in the screen
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKee9.png)

```
class Electro extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Electronique Analogique'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
      body: GridView.count(
        primary: false,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
        crossAxisSpacing: 4,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("clicked"); //we put the function of pdf
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Center(
                child: const Text(
                  'Cour',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Center(
              child: const Text(
                'TD',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Center(
              child: const Text(
                'Correction TD',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Center(
              child: const Text(
                'Exam',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [flutter_pdf_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdf_viewer) plugin for loading pdf files from URL

```
PDFDocument doc = await PDFDocument.fromURL('YOUR PDF URL');
```

**[see complete example here](https://github.com/CrossPT/flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)**